# PHP Datetime query how?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, epoch

Sorry my English a little,
My date column is 1375801584 valuable epoch format.
I wanna only select now and next time records, i want hide history times record.
eg: 19:45 and later.

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("select tarih from table where tarih < '$date' order by tarih ASC");
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
?>
    <tr><td><?php echo date("Y-m-d", $r['tarih']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date("H:i", $r['tarih']); ?></td></tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 2):

You close. Your current query is selecting *older* records (`<`). Try using `>=`:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select date from table where date >= '$date;' order by date ASC");
```

Comment: Thank you for help but not working this code, not list records this query.

Comment: Are you sure you have valid values in your database?

Comment: my date column name is "tarih" (turkish date) i edit my post now.

Comment: query listed to 2013-08-06 19:00 , 2013-08-06 19:30 timed records, but now time is 2013-08-07 00:40 .. I want only 00:38 and later time records, help me please.

Comment: $aqaq = time();
    $sql = mysql_query("select tarih from table where tarih > '$aqaq;' order by tarih ASC");


Thanks for help. I solved my problem.